# jQuery form, exist checking

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, forms

So i am creating a simple form that checks whether or not the value that the user is inputting exists or not in my DB using jQuery. Everything up until now is working so far however i find myself stuck at this next part.

To easily explain i will just show an example of what i am trying to achieve.
For this example i will be "weeden"

weeden has an ID of 255 in the company table of my database.

1. If the user types in "weeden" into the client field
2. To the right of the client field (on the web form), the text **"weeden is unavailable"** will appear

what i would like to have happen  instead is this:  **"ID 255 is unavailable"**

Here is the relevant code.

**HTML FORM**

```
<form action="addrecord.php" method="post" autocomplete="off"/>  
<div class="form-field">
  <label for="client">Client: </label>
  <input type="text" name="client" id="client" class="check-exists" data-type="client" placeholder="#">
  <span class="check-exists-feedback" data-type="client"></span>
</div>
```

**jQuery Function**

```
$.fn.existsChecker = function(){
  return this.each(function(){   
        var interval;

        $(this).on('keyup', function(){
            var self = $(this),
                selfType = self.data('type'),
                selfValue,
                feedback = $('.check-exists-feedback[data-type=' + selfType + ']');

            if(interval === undefined){
                interval = setInterval(function(){

                  if(selfValue !== self.val()){
                      selfValue = self.val();

                      if(selfValue.length >= 1){
                          $.ajax({
                              url: 'check.php',
                              type: 'get',
                              dataType: 'json',
                              data: {
                                    type: selfType,
                                    value: selfValue
                              },
                              success: function(data){
                                  if(data.exists !== undefined){
                                      if (data.exists === true){
                                          feedback.text(selfValue + ' is already taken.');
                                      }else {
                                          feedback.text(selfValue + ' is available');
                                      }
                                  }
                              },
                              error: function(){

                              }
                           });
                       }
                  }
              }, 1000);
          }
      });
  });
};
```

**Check.php**

```
$db= new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=mydb', 'user', 'pass');

if(isset($_GET['type'], $_GET['value'])){

$type = strtolower(trim($_GET['type']));
$value= trim($_GET['value']);

$output = array('exists' => false);


if(in_array($type,
            array('client')
            )
   ){

  switch($type){
      case 'client':
           $check = $db->prepare("
                SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
                FROM company
                WHERE name = :value
            ");
       break;

$check->execute(array('value'=> $value));
$output['exists'] = $check->fetchObject()->count ? true: false;
echo json_encode($output);
```

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I consider myself a beginner, this is my first time working on a web project.

Just to clarify ahead of time, there are many other input fields on the same webform such as: email, date, first, last, etc.
I hope my question was clear enough. Thank you

Comment: It seems like you're returning a number based on how many people exist with the name weedn. Instead adjust your query so that it actually queries to see if weedn exists and if so, return their id

Comment: `$check = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM company WHERE name = :value");`

like this?

Comment: yes, and then make sure you adjust what it returns down the bottom as well

Comment: Well the issue is, if i change what $ouput returns, it will mess up the rest of my form.  There are other fields on the form that i would like their behavior to act as is.

in the code i provided above, i left out the other cases in the switch. same goes for the HTML segment of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your Query to something like this:

```
$check = $db->prepare("
            SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS count
            FROM company
            WHERE name = :value
        ");
```

I assume that your primary key field on the **company**-table is named **id**.

And finally store the id in the `output`-Array

```
$result = $check->fetchObject();
$output['exists'] = $result->count ? true: false;
$output['id'] = $result->id;
```

Then you can output the id like so:

```
if (data.exists === true){
  feedback.text('ID ' + data.id + ' is unavailable');
}
```

Comment: You haven't store the `id` to the `$output` array then how you will get the `data.id` in the response? So, please update the answer with storing `id` to the `$output['id']`..

Comment: when i use this method i get this response on my HTML form.  "ID null is already taken"    i stored ID into the $output array like this    $output['id'] = $check->fetchObject()->id;

Comment: @JosephC please add `console.log(data);` after `success: function(data){`. Open your Console in DevTools (instructions for [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) and [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Tools/Web_Konsole)), submit your form and show us the output (from the console).

Comment: this is what i see in console.  Object {exists: true, id: null}.  i have tried hardcoding $output['id'] and that seems to work fine, so i think the problem lies in storing the result from the query into $output['id']

Comment: @JosephC I've edited my answer, please try the new code. Use `fetchObject` only once, otherwise it will fetch the next row and return `null `.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle everything in query

```
     $db= new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=mydb', 'user', 'pass');

     if(isset($_GET['type'], $_GET['value'])){

         $type = strtolower(trim($_GET['type']));
         $value= trim($_GET['value']);

         $output = array('exists' => false);


        if(in_array($type,array('client'))){

            switch($type){
                 case 'client':
                       $check = $db->prepare("
                    SELECT (CASE WHEN(COUNT(id)>0) THEN id ELSE FALSE END) AS count 
                    FROM company WHERE name = :value ");
                  break;
            }  
            $check->execute(array('value'=> $value));
            $output['exists'] = $check->fetchObject()->count ? true: false;
            echo json_encode($output);
       }
```

In Ajax success

```
      if(data.exists !== undefined){
          if (!data.exists){
                feedback.text(selfValue + ' is already taken.');
          }else {
               feedback.text(selfValue + ' is already taken.');
          }
       }
```